# Can you send a message to clients who have just joined your access point?

Tags: android, wifi

I am wondering if there is a way to send a message to users that have entered your wifi's reach? I am not sure if this is possible or how it's called.

A hint of what to look for or some sample code (if this is possible at all) would be much appreciated!

Comment: You mean you have your custom application running in Android and it needs to detect if the device has joined a new access point or new access points are available?

Comment: Do these users have your application installed, or do you want to make an application to send messages to any handset at all? If you mean you want to find any handset in your wifi range and send them a random message, I think (and hope!) you can't, otherwise we'de be flooded with spam that way?

Comment: I would like to send a message to any Android device that joins the wifi and, no -- they do not have my application installed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only thing that is possible as far as I know is to add software to your accesspoint to do a splash screen (or possibly a login page).

This would not completely solve your use-case, but like the various "free" wifi in bars you do need to log in to first, you need to open a browser first and perform an action, before you have a real connection.

You could just skip the authentication-part, and put your message on the splash screen.

A random example of what you can find on the internet is this: http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/NoCatSplash
I have no experience with it, but it seems to serve above mentioned purpose, and you can easily go from there.

I am aware that this is NOT an android specifi answer, but as far as I know it is not an android specific question: you want to send a message to people connection to your wireless.

Comment: Thanks, I believe I've seen this around airports. Might be an option.